# English Expressions that mean 'almost always'

Tags: vocabulary

I'm looking for an adequate expression for 'almost always':

The sentence I want to use is like
"It almost always happens."

I think 'very often' is a bit weaker than I want.

Any good expression for the above?

Comment: _Very often_ **is** somewhat weaker than _almost always_. And the expression for _almost always_ is _almost always_. What less could you want?

Comment: What John says, plus perhaps even more to the point, *almost always* is the *only* expression that means exactly "almost always" and nothing else. Any other expression will mean something different.

Comment: I almost always use *invariably*, but some people think that only ever means *always*.

Comment: I don't think it's "unclear" what the OP is asking at all. Why was this put on hold? Because you don't think there's a synonym, as per your explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant for "almost always" is "nearly always" or Latin perpetually.

Comment: I don't think *perpetually* means *almost always* it means *never ending*